# SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':' at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:895:18)

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I have written a simple typescript code:

```
var x: number =10;
console.log(x);
```

After compiling tsc filename.ts there was no error

node filename.ts
while trying to see the output of this in visual studio code facing the below error

```
var x: number =10;
     ^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:895:18)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:995:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:815:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:727:14)
    at Function.Module.runMain (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1047:10)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:11
```

I'm not sure what is wrong in this!!

Comment: It looks syntactically correct. Please, provide the entire class or component.

Comment: it looks like your code is treated as JS, not TS...

Comment: I have saved name as demo.ts, that is what confusing me!!

Comment: after  executing `tsc filename.ts` you've to run `node filename.js` but not `node filename.ts`.

Comment: Node can't run TS files.

Answer (score -1):

I also faced same error. It got solved when I ran these two commands while compiling

```
> tsc filename
> node filename
```

instead of filename.ts or filename.js. This reduces drag.
Please let me know if this solves issue. Keep the code same.